# Array object is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this model in Mongoose and NodeJS:

```js
const VisitorSchema = new Schema({
  visits: [{date: Date, path: String, details: String}],
  // ...
});
```

And this code:

```js
// Get all visitors.
VisitorSchema.statics.getAllVisitors = function() {
  try {
    // Return all users.
    return Visitor.find()
      .sort({created: -1})
      .exec();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// Check and print new users.
VisitorSchema.statics.checkPaths = async function() {
  console.log("Checking paths...");
  let visitors = await this.getAllVisitors();
  for (let visitor of visitors) {
    try {
      for (let v of visitors.visits) {
        // ...
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(visitor.visits));
      throw(e);
    }
  }
};
```

Running this function unexpectedly throws:

```
Checking paths...
TypeError: visitors.visits is not iterable
    at Function.VisitorSchema.statics.checkPaths
[object Array]
5efba3a0a97a823909802df5
(node:23663) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: visitors.visits is not iterable
    at Function.VisitorSchema.statics.checkPaths 
    at processTicksAndRejections
    ....
```

I also checked the MongoDB object in the mongo shell and the sub-document `visits` for the relevant document is an array and seems OK:

```
> db.visitors.findOne({_id: ObjectId("...")})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "visits" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
            "date" : ISODate("..."),
            "path" : "/"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

How can an Array object not be iterable?

Comment: Shouldn't `getAllVisitors` be declared as async (`VisitorSchema.statics.getAllVisitors = async function() { ... }`)?

Comment: You're referencing the wrong variable in your 2nd inner for loop. `for (let v of visitors.visits)` should probably be `for (let v of visitor.visits)`.

Comment: @Sven You are correct and that fixed it. Can you write an answer, emphasizing that all array objects are iterable, and if they're not, the bug is elsewhere?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot Can you say more?

Comment: @Sven is correct @miguelmorin, however, you can also try this `visitors.forEach( ( v ) => { console.log(v.visits.id) })`

Comment: @secan Only if the OP meant to `return await Visitor.find().…;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is **always** iterable in JS. Pay attention to the rows in the `visitors` collection, which may lack the `visits` property. If that property is not an array in MongoDB (this is allowed because MongoDB is a NoSQL database) it will still be cast to an empty array from your model definition.

In your specific case, you have a typo:

```js
for (let v of visitors.visits) // plural
```

should probably be

```js
for (let v of visitor.visits) // singular
```